# How to Force Download files via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make my site "www.suruleretv.co" files like mp3, mp4 to force download instead of streaming.

I've tried to add some codes in find online via .htaccess but am getting error after adding it.

```
<FilesMatch "\.mp3$">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

it would help if you could add your code to the question, to clarify what you want and to identify what the issue is.

However, if you want to force files to be downloaded, adding the following in your .htaccess should be enough:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mp3|mp4)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Please keep in mind, that if you only add this part and have nothing else in it, you will have to save your .htaccess file in the same directory as the downloadeable files. It won't work for subfolders, without adding more rules.